# javascript what happens on array push?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have:

```
var something = function () { return 6}

var foo = new something();

var arr = []
var arr2 = []
```

I do `arr2.push(foo)` and `arr.push(foo)`

What happens in the background? Is foo duplicated and put in 2 places? Is foo just foo and what's inside the arrays a reference to foo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: I misread. Because you are invoking the function with `new` you create a new object. Any object is passed by reference.

```
var something = function () { return 6}

var foo = new something();
```

`typeof foo` is an `object` so in this case it is passed by reference.

<del>Pretty sure that `foo` is duplicated since it's a primitive and not an object.</del>

Comment: Thanks, what if it were an object?

Comment: A reference to the object would be passed.

Answer (score 1):

What's inside the arrays are references to the same instance of something. This can be checked easily using for example chrome javascript console...

[image]

As you can see adding a new member `x` to `arr1[0]` got it appearing on `arr2[0]`.